# Android TableLayout With Different Column's Width In A Row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am trying to do my first complex GUI, but now i can't to solve this problem.

[image]

The first column of the first two rows only needs to contain the label, while the second column of the first two rows must occupy the remaining space.

In this snapshot the problem that i noticed is that the first column is larger than i would like.

This is the piece of code that implements that piece of layout.

```
...
...

<TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/linear_layout_background"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:shrinkColumns="*">

       <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPlateValueLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/plateValue"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:ems="5"
            android:text="@string/blank"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </TableRow>

       <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" >

           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ztlLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ztl"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ztlShow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:text="@string/blank"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

       </TableRow>

       <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/isAllowed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/blank"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            </TableRow>

   </TableLayout>
   ...
   ...
```

In addition, since they are really impractical, I would like to ask you some advice on the best approaches to use than this.

Comment: I don't think TableLayout is good for what you're doing.  Just use RelativeLayout and LinearLayout.

Comment: If your requirements permit it, and you don't *have to* have the label to the left of the input field  - it looks like using `TextInputLayout` would be another way to solve for this kind of uniform input-layout, adhering to best practices [design/widget/TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try using layout_weight like this:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#ff00ff"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:shrinkColumns="*">

       <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPlateValueLabel"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Label1:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productID"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:ems="5"
            android:text="Some Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </TableRow>

       <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

           <TextView
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:id="@+id/ztlLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Label2:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:id="@+id/ztlShow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:text="Some Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

       </TableRow>

       <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/isAllowed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some Text"
            android:background="#0088ff"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            </TableRow>

   </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In my case, the main take away here was to use `android:layout_width="0dp"` in all the column view entries.  My table layout has this `android:stretchColumns="*"`.  Otherwise - I didn't need to set any other attributes .. namely **layout_weight** .. wasn't necessary in my case.   Cool - this got me on the right track, thanks

Comment: what about put in textview a large text? why doesn't break words by the width assigned in the parent?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use TableLayout, if I were you. I'd probably use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. You can get the same effect with some of the XML attributes. This is akin to using HTML's `table` attribute vs. using `div`s to simulate tables.

So, instead of a table, you can have LinearLayout inside of LinearLayout to simulate a table.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the advice. Can you show me how can i try to implement that using RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Although [canDroid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23787050/5099208), could be sufficient to some of us, it didn't worked for me, I tried all kind of tricks to make the `TableLayout` to work. I found `LinearLayout` much easier to use, here is an example of `TableLayout` "like" layout using `LinearLayout`, few cells with a thumbnail, and few without.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="94dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/nut1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="94dp"
            android:layout_height="94dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@drawable/one"
            android:contentDescription="@string/nut3"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:saveEnabled="false"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="94dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/nut3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```